# Different Admin language

Tags: admin-menu, admin-bar, language

We are running our WP site in Hungarian but nobody in our team understands this language. We successfully changed admin backend language to our native language but not everything changed. We are still getting notification emails in Hungarian. The top (black) admin bar is also in Hungarian. Woocommerce send orders in Hungarian to admin... Is there a way to change that?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking and there could be many mitigating factors. For example, are there any multilingual plugins installed? Is this only happening with WooCommerce message or are _all_ messages sent in Hungarian? The more details you provide the easier it is for people to help.

Comment: There is no multilingual plugin installed. As you can see from the above image the top admin bar is all in Hungarian even I am logged in as admin and my language is Slovak. All messages to admin are in Hungarian. The menu and all text in admin part is correctly displaying in Slovak according the user setting.

Comment: Maybe also explain how you changed the backend to Slovak. I'm sorry if I sound like I'm asking for a lot of detail but it really helps others who are unfamiliar with your specific setup. Good luck!

Comment: My admin account has Slovak set up. Even when I change my language to English - that means other than site default language - I still see Hungarian text.

Comment: Really sorry @vlado but I'm at a loss on this one. It crosses my mind that when the site was set up, it should have been set up in Slovak and now the only way to fix it might be reinstalling from scratch?? Unfortunately I can't offer any more suggestions. Good luck with this.

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress, since few version there is a setting in each user profile to select a language which have higher priority than site language. This can be the answer of the back office always in Hungarian.

About WooCommerce emails, they are sent in the default website language unless a custom code or a plugin come & change this behaviour.

Unfortunately, without more information, we can't help you more. Maybe you can copy & paste your site health report here? (wp-admin / tools / site health / Tab info and then click on "copy site info to clipboard" button.

Thank you

Comment: I am aware of the per user language setting, but that still does not change some parts. As I said the top black admin bar is still in Hungarian - see the picture above. Some plugins like Elementor was in Hungarian - I just delete the translation file and that helped. 
I tried to insert the health report, but i got error: Too long by 11553 characters